# SWIFT Attach a image to bezierPath

Tags: path, curve, bezier

[image]i need to make a application where i have curved bezier like /\ and i have a small object at the left bottom of it, for example a plane >

use your imagination ;)

I have a value from 0.0 to 1.0 and base on it i want put my plane on the path, for example

- 0.0 plane is on the beginning of the path: >/\
- 0.5 is at halfway: />\
- 1.0 is at the end: />

I know how to do it with animation.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position") then .path = bezierPath
```

its easy!

But I don't need animation! I want to put this plane on the right place when my viewDidAppear.

How to stick UIImage to UIBezierPath and move it along this curve?

Comment: When it comes to programming questions I strongly prefer *not* to use my imagination when figuring out what someone's talking about, and instead ask for a proper problem description to work with. So: Instead of ASCII, can you just attach one or more images that properly show off what you mean?

Comment: ok post updated with an image

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found solution
All you need is to set :

```
let flightAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    flightAnimation.path = ovalShapeLayer.path
    flightAnimation.speed = 0
    flightAnimation.timeOffset = 0.5 // 50% of the path
    flightAnimation.duration = 1.0
```